# Where to put article "a"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, comparison, as

1. It's not as good **a** restaurant as it used to be.
2. It's not as **a** good restaurant as it used to be.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: Both "*It's not as good a restaurant as it used to be*." and "*It's not a restaurant as good as it used to be*." are correct to me.  "*The restaurant is not as good as it used to be*" might be more natural?

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately, the second sentence is incorrect in respect to grammar.

Comment: @SovereignSun, really? I saw the sentence like "*She is a cook as good as her mother*"

Comment: @Dan I guess it was a non-native speaker who wrote it or an uneducated native speaker. Or simply an uneducated person.

Comment: @SovereignSun, I think it's ok if you consider "*It's not a restaurant (that is) as good as it used to be*." , "*She is a cook (who is) as good as her mother*."

Comment: @Dan I'm talking about the OP's second sentence, not yours. Your sentence, "**It's not a restaurant as good as it used to be**" is correct but I wouldn't say such a phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is correct ([*Learning English BBC World Service*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv158.shtml)):

- It's not as good **a** restaurant as it used to be.

> - I hope you will agree that I am as imaginative a cook as my wife (is)!
>
> Note from the above example that if there is an adjective and a noun after the first as, a / an must go between them.

Also noted here ([*English Grammar*](https://www.englishgrammar.org/asas/)):

> - He is as good a cook as his wife is! (NOT He is as a good cook as his wife is.)
>
> When we use adjective + noun after the first as, the article should go before the noun.

Comment: I agree, Alexander. "It's not as good **a** restaurant as it used to be" is definitely the only correct choice.